# Error: Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service while using Spring Cloud Load Balancer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I am trying to migrate from Ribbon to Client Load balancer and having below configuration:

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.6'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
'springCloudVersion', "2020.0.2"


application.properties (library-service)
user-service.ribbon.listOfServers=http://localhost:9091


UserServiceProxy.java
@FeignClient(name="user-service") 
@LoadBalancerClient(name="user-service")
interface UserServiceProxy{}

ApplicationClass.java
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = "com.library.service")
public class LibraryServiceApplication {}
```

I don't understand why I am getting the below error when trying to access user service using a proxy.
Can anyone please help me?

`There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). [503] during [GET] to [http://user-service/users/10] [UserServiceProxy#getUserById(Long)]: [Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service user-service]`

**Ask1**) Cant we use Client LoadBalancer without Eureka server? As we used Ribbon and feign in earlier versions.

Appreciate any help!!

Comment: Load balancer does not recognize ribbon properties

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Spring Cloud LoadBalancer with Eureka, but you cannot use it with Ribbon-specific properties. You can see [in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#simplediscoveryclient), that instead of `ribbon.listOfServers`, `SimpleDiscoveryClient` can be used in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please share an example link for Feign client and SpringCloud Load Balancer?

Comment: For example, this sample uses SC LoadBalancer under the hood: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/feign-eureka